# Metallic Aluminum and Dry Ice

Tags: experimental-chemistry

We see $\ce{2Mg + CO2 -> 2MgO + C}$ , quite often in lab experiments.

Under which conditions can $\ce{4Al + 3CO2-> 2Al2O3 + 3C}$ be used - if chemically feasible?

Answer (score 1):

Based on this (very old) paper - http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00740367#page-1 - the aluminum will ignite if you heat it past the melting point of aluminum oxide, 2060C.